# Can the following integral be solved exactly without approximation ? if so how to evaluate?

Tags: integration, vector-analysis, indefinite-integrals, exponential-distribution, gaussian-integral

$$I=\int d^{3}{\vec{r_{1}}}  \frac{\exp\bigg[-2\alpha\mid\vec{r_{1}}-\vec{R_{2}}\mid^{2}\bigg]}{\mid\vec{r_{1}}-\vec{R_{1}}\mid}$$

Where $\alpha$ is a real positive number and constant. $\vec{R_{1}}$ and $\vec{R_{2}}$ are constant vectors . Integral is over the full space (i.e) $$-\infty<x_{1}<\infty$$
$$-\infty<y_{1}<\infty$$
$$-\infty<z_{1}<\infty$$

Can someone suggest a trick to evaluate this integral ? Is it exactly integratble?

Comment: Looks like it blows up when $\mathbf{r}_1=\mathbf{R}_1$. The numerator is continuous in all of space, and even bounded. I'm not at all sure the integral even exists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answer is just to propose a trick to rewrite the integral as this was asked by OP.

Let us observe that
$$
\frac{1}{|{\bf r_1}-{\bf R}_1|}=\int\frac{d^3q}{(2\pi)^3}e^{i{\bf q}\cdot({\bf r_1}-{\bf R}_1)}\frac{1}{q^2}
$$
and
$$
e^{-2\alpha|{\bf r_1}-{\bf R}_2|^2}=\sqrt{\frac{8\alpha}{\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^\infty dk e^{ik|{\bf r_1}-{\bf R}_2|}e^{-\frac{k^2}{8\alpha}}.
$$
Then, the integral takes the form
$$
\sqrt{\frac{8\alpha}{\pi}}\int\frac{d^3q}{(2\pi)^3}\frac{1}{q^2}
\int_{-\infty}^\infty dke^{-\frac{k^2}{8\alpha}}
\int d^3r_1
e^{i{\bf q}\cdot({\bf r_1}-{\bf R}_1)}e^{ik|{\bf r_1}-{\bf R}_2|}.  
$$
As suggested in the comments, this integral can become singular and is diverging for ${\bf r}_1={\bf R}_1$. This reflects the singularity at the origin of the 1/r potential. Far from the singularity, this is amenable to a multipolar expansion.

Comment: You are welcome.